# Why split after new line is not returning single array using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a string text after fetching an API with a for loop, that returns me a list of names, each name separated by a new line. When I use the code in the snippet, it returns me each name in an individual array, instead of a single array. Is there anything wrong with the RegEx? Could someone please tell me what is wrong? Thank you very much for the help.

```js
function loadMagicItems() {
    fetch('https://api.open5e.com/magicitems/?fields=slug,name,desc,type,rarity&limit=1000'
    ).then(function (responses) {
        return responses.json();
    }).then(function (data) {
        displayMagicItems(data);
    });
};

function displayMagicItems(data) {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
        const magicItemsName = data.results[i].name.split(/\n/);
        console.log(magicItemsName);
    };
};
```

```html
<body onload="loadMagicItems()">
</body>
```

Comment: Check your response data. Each name is seperate.

Comment: could you give an example of the input data you receive and the output you are expecting?

Comment: "*each name separated by a new line*" - no it isn't. Each name property is part of an object in the JSON.

Comment: Split push the result into an array. thats the reason. Solution: use index [0]  in your console log like: console.log(magicItemsName[0]);

Comment: I am sorry I have it confused, because when I was trying to console.log(magicItemsName); without the split(), it returned me a list of the names, each one in a line. That´s why I thought it was separated by a line. I am new at programming JavaScript and still haven't figured out everything. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON data is an array of items. Not all items as one string seperated by a newline character.

The easiest way to get the names of the items, is to use a `map` and return the name of the item.

```js
function loadMagicItems() {
  fetch('https://api.open5e.com/magicitems/?fields=slug,name,desc,type,rarity&limit=1000').then(function(responses) {
    return responses.json();
  }).then(function(data) {
    displayMagicItems(data.results);
  });
};

function displayMagicItems(items) {
  items = items.map(({name}) => name);
  console.log(items);
};
```

```html
<body onload="loadMagicItems()" />
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was able to have it in one array with your map solution. I am sorry I got confused.

Comment: @BraulioPortela NP, that's what learning is for.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is correct, this is behavior expected. For each `name` string you generating an array spllited by `\n`. If you want join the results you can do:

```js
function displayMagicItems(data) {
    const singleArrayWithNames = []
    for (let i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
        const magicItemsName = data.results[i].name.split(/\n/);
        singleArrayWithNames.push(...magicItemsName) // pushing names extracted to new array
    };
    console.log("all names: ", singleArrayWithNames)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `name` property is already seperated, and your'e using `.split`
each iteration, it's creating a new array each time.

```js
function loadMagicItems() {
    fetch('https://api.open5e.com/magicitems/?fields=slug,name,desc,type,rarity&limit=1000'
    ).then(function (responses) {
        return responses.json();
    }).then(function (data) {
        displayMagicItems(data);
    });
};

function displayMagicItems(data) {
    const magicItemsName=[]
    for (let i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
        
        magicItemsName[i] = data.results[i].name;
        
    };
    console.log(magicItemsName);
};
```

```html
<body onload="loadMagicItems()">
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I was also able to have it in one array using you code too. I am sorry I got confused.